# web scraping with beautiful soup 4. remove tr element based on class. python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tr

I am scraping from this page: 'https://kenpom.com/index.php?y=2018'

I have the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url ='https://kenpom.com/index.php?y=2018'
r = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')

table = soup.find('table',{'id':'ratings-table'}).tbody
teams = table.findAll('tr')4
```

The variable `teams` contains 367 `tr` elements. Most of them do not have a class, but some of them have a class of 'thead1' and some have a class of 'thead2'. How do I remove all of the `tr` elements in `teams` that have either 'thead1' or 'thead2' as a class?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`[x for x in teams if 'class' not in x.attrs or ('thead1' not in x.attrs['class']  and 'thead2' not in x.attrs['class'])]`

Answer (score 0):

This one liner should work:

```
newTeams = [x for x in teams if (type(x) != thead1) and (type(x) != thead2) ]
```

Comment: I'll test this when I get home. But wouldn't thead1 and thead2 need to be in quotes?

Answer (score 0):

If you opt for [.extract()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract), it will help you kick out those `tr`'s you don't wanna keep. Check out the following implementation.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url ='https://kenpom.com/index.php?y=2018'

r = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')

table = soup.find('table',{'id':'ratings-table'}).tbody
[tr.extract() for tr in table.find_all('tr',class_=["thead1","thead2"])]
teams = table.find_all('tr')
print(len(teams))
```

Result:

```
351
```